# Problems with Paste X-flipped pose

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to copy the first frame to the last frame by ctrl c and shift ctrl v but it doesn't work well.. how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it must have to do with a bad bone orientation, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I did..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LowerLeg.R IK *Pole Angle* is bad, it should be 0:

[image]

Also, move the knees a bit forwards so that Blender knows in what direction they are supposed to bend:

[image]

When you'll have done that you'll need to redo the poses.

Comment: the pole angle of LowerLeg.L  should be 0 also?

Comment: no left leg seems ok, is it not the case?

Comment: yah you are right. It work well now, thank you for all the help!